# Problems with handling queries to a css-styled mainpage of a GoogleApp when calling an imported class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this app.yaml file:

```
application: *****
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.py

builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
```

And this main.py script:

```
import service
...
...
class UrlHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    if self.request.query_string != '':
      service.MainPage()
    else:
      self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/main.html', {}))
...
...
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? I want ...mainpage/ requests to land on the main html page with a css style sheet and ...mainpage/?... requests to be handled by the MainPage class in service called from main.py.

Comment: I suggest editing your title.  "Problems with importing a class in python" is not really descriptive of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Standard questions apply: what have you tried, what isn't working, etc.

Comment: If I do for example ..../?type=retrieve&name=example it returns a blank page instead of some text which should've been generated by service.py

Comment: Can you clarify what this has to do with css? If your .css files are in `static/`, your app won't see the requests for them.

Comment: I want to generate an html page when people visit my app via [http://myappname.appspot.com](http://myappname.appspot.com), which works fine. But when I do a request to that page via [http://myappname.appspot.com/?type=retrieve&name=example](http://myappname.appspot.com/?type=retrieve&name=example) it should generate a text file with information about the service "example", which it doesn't. It generates a blank page.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `/mainpage/` and `/mainpage/?foo=bar` should be the same resource - adding query string parameters should not cause your site to render something totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service.MainPage()` isn't going to have access to the `request` and `response` objects that the framework has stuck on to the `webapp.RequestHandler` instance that `get()` sees.

You could pass `self` to `service.MainPage()` (assuming that's a function, and not a class that you're creating an instance of and them doing nothing with).

Or, even simpler, (and assuming that `MainPage` is a `webapp.RequestHandler` subclass), move the 'render templates/main.html on no query string' logic there, since it's only a few lines.